# How to validate that there are no spaces between two characters in a string, using regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to validate that there *NO* spaces between two characters (or in the middle of a name) in a string.

I want a regex that will accept " ab " and reject " a  b " .

I tried using `"\\s*((_[a-zA-z]+)|([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*))\\s*"`
and  `"(\\s*\\S\\s*)"` .

p.s I don't care about spaces before and after the character\word.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how about `(\\s*\\S{2,}\\s*)`  or ``(\\s*\\S+\\s*)``

Comment: I guess `s.matches("\\s*\\S+\\s*")` is what you need.

Comment: So, if `^\s*\S+\s*$` doesn't match "<space><space><space>" does that mean there is a space in the middle of the name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`\\s*\\S+\\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/doFgv6/1)`

- `\\s*` match zero or more spaces
- `\\S+` match one or more non-space characters
- `\\s*` match zero or more spaces

  ```
  System.out.println(" aa ".matches("\\s*\\S+\\s*")); // true
  System.out.println(" a bc ".matches("\\s*\\S+\\s*")); // false
  ```

Note : `matches` implicitly include starting of match `^` and ending of match `$` anchors and there is no need of capturing group `()` unless you are trying to fetch the specified match out of your data.

To match only alphabets use `\\s*[a-zA-Z]+\\s*`

Comment: If `matches implicitly include` anchors `^$`, will I get an error, or will the regex run any differently if I include them in the regex ?

Comment: you can post a new question and tag me to answer it because seems like you already know the answer of your question

Comment: I'm really not sure, but I suspect the answer is it has no affect. Which makes it mildly disturbing to see `matches implicitly include starting of match ^ and ending of match $ anchors` as a qualification time and time again on different posts.

Comment: the `matcher` (used by Pattern which further used by `matches`) which states in docs as well as in source code  `The matches method attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern`

Comment: I imagine it does say that, so who cares if `^$` anchors are used at the beginning/end. It looks strange `(?=[\w]*$)a\d_\db` no ?

Comment: today , apparently you cares the most

Answer (score 1):

Try `^\s*\w+\s*$`

This looks for zero or more spaces then any word characters `[a-z0-9_]` then zero or more spaces again before the end of the string

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/LTHkLv/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can match exactly N characters with `{N}`

So, you can just use:

```
\\S{2}
```

which matches any two non-whitespace characters; or

```
\\w{2}
```

which matches two word characters.

```
 [a-zA-Z]{2}
```

two letters, etc.

Comment: That works for the example I gave but I would also like to reject " a bc " or any string with a space between characters

Comment: @MayaSela so would you like to allow spaces only at the beginning and end of strings?  Your question isn't clear.

Comment: OK sorry about that. Yes I would like to allow only strings with spaces at the beginning and the end (the spaces are optional there, but not allowed between characters)